# How do I get a handle to the Start button in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I use:

```
Hwnd hStart = ::FindWindow ("Shell_TrayWnd",NULL);  // get HWND of taskbar first
hStart = ::FindWindowEx (hStart, NULL,"BUTTON", NULL); // get HWND of start button
```

to get start button's handle. It's running properly on Windows XP, 
but in Windows 7, `::FindWindowEx (hStart, NULL,"BUTTON", NULL)` always returns 0, and `GetLastError()` returns 0, too.

Why is that?

Comment: I suppose that the start button on Windows 7 has no longer the class `BUTTON`, but I may be wrong. You can check with Spy++ what it is now, but I strongly advice you not to mess with fundamental UI elements like the Start button. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What would you do with a Start button handle even if you got one?

Comment: Gabe, I just studying about HOOK. :)

Comment: For reference, there is no start button at all on Windows 8 preview :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Windows 7 the start button, which has class name `"Button"`, is a child of the desktop window. Your code assumes that the start button is a child of the window named `"Shell_TrayWnd"` which does indeed appear to be the way the taskbar and start menu were implemented on XP.

For Windows 7 you want to use something like this:

```
hStart = ::FindWindowEx(GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, "Button", NULL);
```

Although I think it would be better search for it by name to be sure that you get the right button.

```
hStart = ::FindWindowEx(GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, "Button", "Start");
```

I'm not sure how Vista implements its taskbar and start menu, but you can use Spy++ to find out.

Having said all of this, it would be much better if you can find a way to achieve your goals without poking around in such implementation specific details.

Comment: And don't forget that in Windows 8 everything will be completely different.

Comment: @Mark Yes, now would be an excellent time to clean house and abandon such hacks

Comment: Thanks! I've tried `hWnd = ::FindWindow("Button","Start");` ,it works in Windows 7,while in XP it just returns NULL.I guess the start button does be a child window of the taskbar in XP,while in Windows 7 it's a independent window. :)

Comment: that doesn't seem to work on Windows 10, any idea about how to make it relevant again?

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein Use a tool like WinSpy or Spy++. Looks like it might have caption `"Start"` and class name `"Start"`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean to call it like this? `FindWindowEx(GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, "Start", "Start");`

Comment: I guess so. I've not tried. Did you? Remember that this is pure hacking.

Answer (score -1):

::FindWindow (L"Shell_TrayWnd",NULL);

this code is for complete taskbar