# Obtain Handle to Task Bar

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a WinAPI function to retrieve a handle to the Task Bar?

The purpose is to determine the Task Bar docking setting (ABE_LEFT, ABE_RIGHT, ABE_BOTTOM, ABE_TOP). The function `SHAppBarMessage` requires the taskbar handle to retrieve the docking information. Unless there is another way to determine the task bar docking setting without needing the handle?

I'm aware of this method which works ok but I am not sure it works on all Windows versions:

```
HWND taskBar = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
```

Comment: Up to Windows 7 inclusive, that should work. Windows 8 and upwards, its changed. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569620/how-do-i-get-a-handle-to-the-start-button-in-windows-7) for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a documentation bug. You don't need to provide a window handle in the [APPBARDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773184.aspx) structure for the [ABM_GETTASKBARPOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787949.aspx) when calling [SHAppBarMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108.aspx)<sup>1)</sup>.

The following code properly returns the location of the taskbar (tested on Windows 10 x64):

```
#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")
#include <stdexcept>

RECT GetTaskbarPos() {
    APPBARDATA abd = { 0 };
    abd.cbSize = sizeof( abd );
    if ( !::SHAppBarMessage( ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, &abd ) ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "SHAppBarMessage failed." );
    }
    return abd.rc;
}
```

Update: The question was really asking for the docking enumeration value. That is returned as well:

```
#include <shellapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")
#include <stdexcept>

UINT GetTaskbarDockingEdge() {
    APPBARDATA abd = { 0 };
    abd.cbSize = sizeof( abd );
    if ( !::SHAppBarMessage( ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, &abd ) ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "SHAppBarMessage failed." );
    }
    return abd.uEdge;
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *It would be awkward if you needed the well hidden window handle of the taskbar to send this message. If you had the window handle already, you could simply call [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) instead.*

Comment: I wonder how this handles when the taskbar is on multiple monitors.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: This retrieves the taskbar position of the primary display only. To get the taskbar position on other displays, call [GetMonitorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144901.aspx) instead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: When calling `GetMonitorInfo`, you'll have to work out the docking yourself though. It's not part of the [MONITORINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145065.aspx) structure.

Comment: @IInspectable the purpose is to obtain the Task Bar docking setting not the position, ie `.uEdge`

Comment: @JakeM: This is returned in the `APPBATDATA` structure as well. I'll update this answer once I'm at my PC.